# I want to edit HTML code in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to edit a sidebar menu in WordPress, however I am no expert in PHP.

I want to move the anchor tag up a level to wrap about the li tag, so the entire thing links instead of just the text.

Code Example:

```
<ul><li><a href="#">Menu Item #1</a></li><li><a href="#">Menu Item #2</a></li><li><a href="#">Menu Item #3</a></li></ul>
```

And I want the code to be as follows:

```
<ul><a href="#"><li>Menu Item #1</li></a><a href="#"><li>Menu Item #2</li></a><a href="#"><li>Menu Item #3</li></a></ul>
```

How could I go about achieving this in WordPress?

Comment: I appreciate you're no expert in PHP, but can you at least share the section of your PHP file so that we can see?

Comment: There are tons of ways of doing this -

Comment: _“And I want the code to be as follows”_ - no, you don’t, because that would be invalid HTML - UL can only have LI as children, you can not insert a link at this level. _“so the entire thing links instead of just the text.”_ - for that you don’t need to mess with the HTML structure, but should change the _formatting_ instead. Likely your theme has put either a padding on the LI or a margin on the links - you’d want to replace that with a padding on the links.

Comment: `<li><a>` is usually the way to go, the other way round is not valid HTML. I assume your problem lies within the CSS instead. Can you create a [mcve] for us? Edit: Yes, what @CBroe said, really.

Comment: in css, display the <a tags as blocks - then it will fill out the li

Comment: You might want to work with Walker_Nav_Menu class to change the structure of WP menu. Since you have no experience with PHP, you might want to play around your styline to achieve your goal. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu

Comment: Thank you for the responses, i'll go about changing the CSS.

Comment: Nick, if you were able to solve your issue, consider either deleting your question or posting an answer to it yourself, then mark it accepted. Cheers!